# Calling a subprocess in python when an argument is passed by parameter

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to call a subprocess, this is the subprocess:

```
def data_PID(pid):

   print(pid)

   pid = str(pid)

   data = subprocess.getoutput("ps -l | grep pid ")

   print(data)
```

The PID is asked by console, and I want to search the use the value of that PID in the subprocess.getoutput but I don't know how to do that, for example if I write in the console that the PID is 4567, I want the subprocess to make
"ps -l | grep 4567"
If anyone knows how to do this I will thank him.

Comment: don't do this. Use `psutil` module.

Comment: else you're asking how to format a string with arguments... `"ps -l | grep {}".format(pid)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @dbeer. If you want to use psutil here the example:

```
import psutil

def get_process_by_pid(pid: int):

    process = None
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if p.pid == pid:
            process = p
            break

    return process
```

Then you can use the `process` object and get all the process info, if you want the info in a dict structure just call `process.as_dict()`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a bad idea to use a subprocess when an API is available. The [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) module can be used to get the information you're looking for. It's much better to do this than to launch a separate process and parse the output because:

1. It'll save you the parsing logic, which is usually hard to maintain.
2. It avoids the additional possibilities for failure introduced by launching another process.
3. It's faster.

However, to answer your first question, if you just want to write a variable into a string:

```
cmd = "ps -l | grep %s" % (pid)
data = subprocess.getoutput(cmd)
```